# Woocommerce Add product weight below brief description

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

good afternoon.
can you help me?

I am trying to add the product weight below the short description.

However, it is not working.

Look: https://prnt.sc/15mk1e1

https://nutre.barbas.digital/produto/western-bacon-cheeseburger/

I added this item along with the brief description manually.
https://prnt.sc/15mk2r5

I would like it to be automatic.

For that I created this snippet:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','ts_add_text_short_descr');

function ts_add_text_short_descr($description){
    global $product;  
    $weight_unit = get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit');
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
    if ( $product->has_weight() ) {
        $text= '<span class="barbasWeight">Peso: <span class="barbasWeight-values"> '.$product->get_weight(). $weight_unit . '</span></span>';
        return $description.$text;
    }
}
```

It worked well, however, it doesn't work on variable products.

Can you tell me how I can do this?

Thank you very much

Comment: I think it will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65708223/get-weight-value-from-woocommerce-variations-of-a-variable-product

Comment: Hi,@אישנחמד thank you very much for the nomination.

I've tested this method, but unfortunately it captures all the weights and displays them all,

But I'm going to delve into the model to try to better understand how to solve this